# Unity scripting, highlight UI button

Tags: unity-game-engine

I know that you can use `EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(gameObject);` to change button to select color, but how do you make it to highlighted color?

https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject.html
there's a `EventSystems.BaseEventData pointer` variable not sure what option i have under that, it might be the solution?

Comment: Are you talking about the Game or Editor? Highlight what UI button? From legacy UI or TMP? Give us more details!

Comment: TMP, in game view, for ui button theres select color and highlight color

Comment: You don't use code to change the color while the game is running. That's done natively. You just configure what colors (or animations or whatnot) you want when Pressed or Highlighted. You don't need a call to `SetSelectedGameObject()` to set a color if you press a button.

Comment: `SetSelectedGameObject() ` set the item to select color so if i hit enter it press
im wondering if i can do this for highlight color